# Questions about glPixelStorei() alignment

Tags: c, opengl

Every 2 values in this array represent 16 pixels. (8 binary values per element)

```
GLubyte character[24] = {
    0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00,
    0xff, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xc0
};
```

and this is my code to render my bitmap.

```
void init(){
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
}

void render(){
    glBitmap(8, 12, 0.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, character);
}
```

but when I change glBitmap(8, etc.) to glBitmap(10, etc.) , it doesn't work.

to make it work, I need to change,

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
```

to

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

My problem is, I have no idea why this works...

I just know that

```
GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1
```

tells OpenGL to just go to next address without alignment.

I don't see any relationship between setting ALGINMENT to 1 and my bitmap's length.

Could somebody explain what's going on?

Comment: The unpack alignment is the boundary that each row begins on in memory. You have 8 pixels per row, with type `GL_BITMAP`, so each row begins on an 1-byte boundary (1-bit per-pixel). It shouldn't really work with unpack alignment set to 2 as best I can tell. I think you're just getting very lucky in that you have padded the array with 00's.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: I copied my code from http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter08.html#name1                        I'm sorry but I don't really know what you're talking about...did I do something wrong?

Comment: @BDL thanks I deleted that, but I still don't understand how a bitmap width 8 can be expected to work by passing a width of 10. `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` is about about row alignement, so perhaps that makes it magically work.

Comment: @WeatherVane The data is 2bytes per row. In the working example, 8bits are drawn to screen, and another 8bits are skipped due to the alignment. Theoretically all values up to 16 should work (since there are 16bit per row). But I also cannot explain why 10 with alignment=2 is not working.

Comment: @BDL: That may be down to endian issues. I can't really say because "doesn't work" is such a vague way of describing a problem :-\

Comment: So basically `GL_ALIGNMENT, 2` skips all my 0x00 because `2` means to skip the next address? if so, then that means `4` means skip 4 times, right?

Comment: @Ihatestackoverflow: No, that would be stride. Alignment boundaries and stride are two different things. One is a constant that is added to some element to figure out the address of the next element, the other is a rule that establishes where those addresses are allowed to begin. It's possible to have strides and alignments that are incompatible (as you have seen). An alignment requirement of 1 machine unit is compatible with any stride; it's the exception rather than the rule. It's the rows that have alignment requirements here, and the stride is the number of bits per-row.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman `One is a constant that is added to some element to figure out the address of the next element`     that would be Alignment and `a rule that establishes where those addresses are allowed to begin`  is stride, am I right?

Comment: @Ihatestackoverflow: No, you have that backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going back to some historical spec documents (`glBitmap()` is a **very** obsolete call), the alignment rule for bitmaps is (page 136 of the OpenGL 2.1 spec):

```
k = a * ceiling(w / (8 * a))
```

Where:

- `w` is the width, under the assumption that `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` is not set.
- `a` is the value of `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`.
- `k` is the number of bytes used per row. Note that each row will always start on at least a byte boundary, no matter how the parameters are set.

Substituting the values from your example, for `w = 8`, we get:

- 1 byte per row with `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` of 1.
- 2 bytes per row with `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` of 2.

and for `w = 10`, we get:

- 2 bytes per row with `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` of 1.
- 2 bytes per row with `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` of 2.

Based on this, unless you also have other `GL_UNPACK_*` parameters set, you should get the same output for width 10 no matter if `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is 1 or 2. If this is not the case, this looks like a bug in the OpenGL implementation.